# How do I import storage.json files?

Tags: tampermonkey

I can't seem to find a way to do this within Tampermonkey's utitilies->import methods as it seems to only accept scripts.  I've tried exporting all (included storage.json files), modifying the zip, then importing that zip with the new storage.json but to no avail.

Is this possible?  If not, what alternatives to I have?  For now I'm going to have to resort to users manually importing/exporting what each of the GM values should have via a textbox, but this is far from ideal.

Comment: There's a checkbox on the top of the Utitlities page: `Include Tampermonkey settings`

Comment: That worked, but why exactly is that part of 'setting' instead of the other option 'storage; (which I did have checked)

Comment: I also find this behavior confusing. Maybe we should notify the author.